# Django Tutorial: unexplained 404 error after completing first page

Tags: python, django

I finished https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

The intended behaviour works. My polls index is showing. But there is one unintended consequence that I don't understand. When I go to `localhost:8000` I get a page not found. Why?

This is my `mysite/mysite/urls.py` as the tutorial explained.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

The server says:

```
Not Found: /
[11/Feb/2016 04:25:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2010
```

When I delete the polls line, the 404 disappears. I.e.:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Now the server says:

```
Not Found: /
[11/Feb/2016 04:24:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
```

So I guess it is some default quirk but I still don't fully know if I am making a mistake or if this is defined behaviour. My other code is the same as in the code snippets of the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial does not define what will happen when you go to your site root, it only deals with the `polls` app. You have to add a url mapping if you want to see something when you browse to `http://localhost:8080/`.

As a simple example, try making the following changes in your `mysite/urls.py`:

```
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='site_index'),
    ...
]
```

From now on you should see the index view of `polls` app when you browse to your site root.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I also tested the code, it works :)

Answer (score 5):

Interesting observation! Never noticed that before.

When you access a URL, Django tries to match it with the all the defined patterns (in the order of definition). For the first pattern it matches, the corresponding view will be called.

But if there is no URL pattern defined, then django will print `Not found: {url}` that you see in the `runserver` shell. And it will try to raise 404 exception, as expected.

But in the `debug` mode, it does a bit extra.
Let's examine this function in `django/views/debug.py`:

```
def technical_404_response(request, exception):
    # some extra code here
    if (not tried                           # empty URLconf
        or (request.path == '/'
            and len(tried) == 1             # default URLconf
            and len(tried[0]) == 1
            and getattr(tried[0][0], 'app_name', '') == getattr(tried[0][0], 'namespace', '') == 'admin')):
        return default_urlconf(request)
    # more extra code here
```

What Django tries to do here is check how many URL patterns it tried. If specific conditions meet, it will try to return through the `default_urlconf`.
These specific conditions are:

- if there is no URL pattern defined
- if the tried URL is '/', and the only URL pattern defined is for the `admin` app

So what we learn from here that if no URL pattern is defined, then Django will always call the `default_urlconf`. Try deleting the `admin` URLs also, and then access any random URL. You will always get something like this:

```
Not Found: /random/url/
[11/Feb/2016 04:24:23] "GET /random/url/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
```

Now let us look at the `default_urlconf` code:

```
def default_urlconf(request):
    "Create an empty URLconf 404 error response."
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(DEFAULT_URLCONF_TEMPLATE)
    c = Context({
        "title": _("Welcome to Django"),
        "heading": _("It worked!"),
        "subheading": _("Congratulations on your first Django-powered page."),
        "instructions": _("Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. "
            "Next, start your first app by running <code>python manage.py startapp [app_label]</code>."),
        "explanation": _("You're seeing this message because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your "
            "Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!"),
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type='text/html')
```

(It returns a proper `HttpResponse` => 200 HTTP code)

Comment: Besides a solid explanation, what's really valuable about this answer is that you showed me how to tackle a question like this next time. Look into the source. I missed that point, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In case one faced similar problem as I did.

I am building an API with django rest framework. The endpoint expects the current user to be authenticated with token. I am using [drf-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt).

I realized my problem was passing the token in the wrong format from the front-end thus the user is rendered AnonymousUser.

```
  Get(endpoint) {
    if (this.token !== null) {
      let auth = `bearer ${this.token}`;
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: auth
      });

      let fullurl = `${this.baseUrl}${endpoint}`;
      return this.http
        .get(fullurl, { headers: headers })
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
  }
```

Changing bearer to **Bearer** as it's supposed to be resolved the problem.