# How to retain the development page

Tags: python, django

Once I started populating the "urlpatterns" list in urls.py. I am no longer able to see the development page.

How can I retain it?

Edit: By default it is like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have changed to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Also, "development page" I meant the default (initial page), like below.
[image]

Comment: can you specify your question? What have you change? show us your urls.py. Did you start with the Django tutorial (https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)?

Comment: @Tobit: I made changes to my question.

Comment: what else do you see, instead of the development page? The other urls (admin and blog) are working?

Comment: @Tobit Ya other links are working. How can I keep the initial development page? Any ideas?

Comment: if I understand the page right 'and you have not configured any URLs' with adding 'blog/' to the urls.py you have change the URLs and Django will not show the 'development page'.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331309/4098053

Comment: Why do you want to keep that page? It's only for getting started.

Comment: Ya, I like that page. The page cheers me up.

Answer (score 2):

if you really need it, you can add it manually with path. For example:

```
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('start/', default_urlconf),
]
```